# Bad CPU type ~ core2-32-poky-linu - Error compiling for board Intel® Edison

Tags: arduino, intel-edison

I wanted to develop a mini-project with Intel Edison + Grove and Arduino after months I didn't use it.

It used to work fine but when I want to upload and run a project now, I got the the following error in Arduino:

```
fork/exec /Users/Dudis/Library/Arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/core2-32-poky-linux/1.6.2+1.0/i686/pokysdk/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux/i586-poky-linux-g++: bad CPU type in executable
Error compiling for board Intel® Edison.
```

I recently updated Mac OS to Catalina which does not support 32-bit programs if I understood correctly but I also found out that Intel is no longer support Edison and I couldn't find a way to update the library or make it work.

Could anyone help what I should do to be able to upload and run project through Arduino & Intel Edison?

Comment: I guess the best is to browse and ask on https://github.com/edison-fw resources.

Comment: Couple of related links: https://github.com/edison-fw/meta-intel-edison/issues/78, https://github.com/edison-fw/meta-intel-edison/issues/98.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to set up a CROPS environment https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.0.2/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#gs-development-methods and build edison-fw in that including the SDK.

The SDK will allow you to build C code for the Edison, while the new kernel with ACPI might be able to load the drivers you need for the Grove device in the kernel.

Comment: Could you please advice me on this further? I don't really understand much from that libraries :/

Comment: CROPS leverages Docker Containers to set up a Build Host that is not running Linux (e.g. Microsoft® Windows™ or macOS®).

Inside that you build an image for Edison and an SDK (tools for your host that build applications for the Edison).

See https://edison-fw.github.io/meta-intel-edison/